# Здравствуйте , помогите решить задачу с ACMP "Функция - 2 " на Python

Tags: python

Условия: "(Время: 1 сек. Память: 16 Мб Сложность: 38%)
Описана рекурсивная функции с тремя параметрами F(a, b, c):

```
если a ≤ 0 или b ≤ 0 или c ≤ 0, то F(a, b, c) = 1
если a > 20 или b > 20 или c > 20, то F(a, b, c) = F(20, 20, 20)
если a < b и b < c, то F(a, b, c) = F(a, b, c-1) + F(a, b-1, c-1) - F(a, b-1, c)
иначе F(a, b, c) = F(a-1, b, c) + F(a-1, b-1, c) + F(a-1, b, c-1) - F(a-1, b-1, c-1)
```

Однако, если указанную функцию реализовать напрямую, то даже для небольших значений **`a`**, **`b`** и **`c`** (например, a = 15, b = 15, c = 15), программа будет работать несколько часов! 
Необходимо реализовать эффективный алгоритм вычисления функции `F()`, который успеет найти любое ее значение менее чем за одну секунду!

Входные данные
Входной файл **INPUT.TXT** содержит три целых числа `a`, `b`, `c` - параметры функции `F (-104 ≤ a,b,c ≤ 104)`.

Выходные данные
В выходной файл **OUTPUT.TXT** выведите значение функции `F(a, b, c)`.

Примеры
№   **INPUT.TXT**   **OUTPUT.TXT**

```
1) 1 1 1           2

2)    2 2 2 4

3)  10 4 6  523

4)  50 50 50    1048576
```

Comment: вам нужна меморизация или около того. Либо вычислить ВСЮ таблицу от (0.0.0) до (20.20.20) снизу вверх. тут экспоненциальный взрыв идёт если в лоб делать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вам поможет мемоизация:

```
import functools

@functools.cache
def F(a, b, c):
    if a <= 0 or b <= 0 or c <= 0:
        return 1

    if a > 20 or b > 20 or c > 20:
        return F(20, 20, 20)

    if a < b and b < c:
        return F(a, b, c-1) + F(a, b-1, c-1) - F(a, b-1, c)
    else:
        return F(a-1, b, c) + F(a-1, b-1, c) + F(a-1, b, c-1) - F(a-1, b-1, c-1)

print(F(150, 150, 150))
```

Основной смысл - только 1 раз вычислять F(x, y, z) и в следующий раз, если такая связка {x, y, z} встретится - использовать значение без вычисления

Это существенно увеличивает скорость

Вот можете почитать:
https://habr.com/ru/post/335866/

Comment: Спасибо большое , все работает